# MATCH function not working on dates, excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi, I'm on excel 2016.

My match function isn't working, I would expect the match function to return '1'.

Both columns A and C are dates format, not text or numbers.

My match function works fine from column H to L, when I'm using numbers.

Anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: You missed last parameter of match function. Try `=MATCH(C1,A1:A8,0)`.

Comment: As @Harun24hr wrote: you have to add 0 for the optional param match_type: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a